# Dynamically instantiate a Ruby class similar to Java

Tags: java, ruby

How can this line in Java be translated to Ruby:
    String className = "java.util.Vector";
    ...
    Object o = Class.forName(className).newInstance();

Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
Object::const_get('String').new()
```

Comment: If you'd like to instantiate a class inside a module you just use the module instead of `Object`. `MyCoolModule::Submodule.const_get('MyString').new`

Comment: What if you don't even know the submodule?

Answer (score 26):

If you're using ActiveSupport (i.e. Rails), there is a method added to `String` that does this:

```
"String".constantize.new
```